# Cast DataRow [] to string array fires exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."

Tags: c#

I need a string array of the first column of the DataRow [] drs. I tried below one line code but it is not working.

The datatype in the DataTable is Int, I need to connvert it to string array.

Am I missing some? Please suggest me.

```
DataRow[] drs = ds.Tables[1].Select();
```

---

Sorry I need one column value to string array.

```
 string[] drsArray = drs
                .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(row => row.Field<string>("role_id")) //Here getting the exception
```

---

I have tried the @Daniel's logic with ,Its working now. Now Is there possible to reduce some line of code Please.

```
 string[] drsArray = (drs
                        .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(row => row.Field<int>("role_id"))
                 .Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Could you explain if you want to extract all the row values of the first column or all the values of the first row?

Comment: @Steve, Thanks I need all value of first column. I have corrected my question. Still having the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `ToString` on it instead:

`drs[0].ItemArray.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();`

Comment: This will return all the columns in the first row as strings. Not sure if this is what the OP is asking.

Comment: You should use Convert.ToString(i) to handle nullable values

Comment: @Steve It might not be what the OP *wanted*, but it's what the OP *asked*.

Comment: _I need a string array of the first column of the DataRow [] drs_  So, I read first column of the drs array. Asked for a clarification above.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Thanks Its working as   string[] drsArray = (drs
                        .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(row => row.Field<int>("role_id"))
                 .Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());

Comment: @DanielMann Can I reduce the code ? If possible Please suggest for best

Answer (score 1):

An old fashioned way should be enough in your case. (At least, in my opinion, it is more readable)

```
List<string> firstCol = new List<string>()
foreach(DataRow row in drs)
    firstCol.Add(row[0].ToString());
```

Of course a List could be seen as an array without to much problems

```
foreach(string s in firstCol)
    Console.WriteLine(s));
```